# Need Batch file help searching for specific string being created in another rolling open session?

Tags: batch-file, session, cmd, full-text-search

Thanks.  Thought I'd try writing a batch file to kill another open cmd session that  is constantly open churning out lots of scrolling info.

I got a bit carried away and am now outta my league so to speak.

Basically I am trying to search for "£000.00" within a each emerging line of tet that appears in the other running open command window.  The running command session is named in the window as C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe but is does have a valid .exe process name in task manager while running and open.

The batch file code below is as far as I've got.

The idea is that when the above string is found in the other process that process/program get closed down them re-launched.

This is as far as I've got.

```
@echo off
@echo off
title Shut down other process and relaunch

:loop
start /d "C:\Users\Desktop" ActiveDOSprogram.exe
::       @setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::       @echo off
::       set stringfound=1
find /c "*£000.00*" C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe && (echo found %date% %time%:~0,-3% >> "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Crash_Report.txt"
taskkill /IM ActiveDOSprogram.exe /F
timeout /t 20
start /d "C:\Users\Desktop" ActiveDOSprogram.exe
goto loop
```

So when I tried this without any variables and in a loop and I think i nearly blew my PC!
Reason I'm stuck is I'm really a novice at this (but trying) and I got as far as I think I need a variable in there somewhere, that only move's to the next line (taskkill+restart) when £000.00 is found in the other process.

Thanks

wingman

Comment: Enter `FIND /?` at your Command prompt and you'll note that `find /c "*£000.00*" C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` does not do what you have assumed. Find reads within strings or files, it is trying to read and count lines within the cmd.exe file not output within a scrolling window.

Comment: It sounds like you want to write a cmd script that can get a copy of stdout and stderr from another process. Is that right? If so, this is probably past the inbuilt capabilities of the cmd shell. You might look toward PowerShell to be able to do something like that.

Comment: The script would need to monitor the text output of another program using another session in dos.  And return a value to be able to shut that program down if "£000.00" appears in that text.   Can I only use cmd script  for static and not live updating files are you saying?  The text in the other open session stays in the buffer memory also in case that's relevant.

Comment: Can anybody help?